# Word add-ins are not displayed when document is edited within MS Teams

Tags: office-js, microsoft-teams

I have a custom word addin which has been deployed via my Office 365 admin center to all users in my organization. When I edit a word document within MS Teams I am unable to see my custom admin. The add-in doesnt appear under Insert -> Office Add-Ins tab in Word under Microsoft Teams. Is there any setting that I am missing for the same? I can view the add-in if I edit the word document outside Ms Teams (i.e. within Office Desktop or Office 365 web)

[image]

Comment: If you choose **Edit in Desktop** for the file, does the add-in appear in the **Office Add-ins** dialog? Another thing to try: In the team/channel, click **Open in SharePoint**. Then open the file from there. Does the add-in appear?

Comment: @RickKirkham The addin is visible when the document is edited in Desktop. And when I hit Open in Sharepoint and open the document I can see the addin.

Comment: @Codecrasher99 Are you able to see the add-ins now?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT I am still unable to see the add-ins.

Comment: We are facing the same issue, seems missing functionality within the [tag:microsoft-teams]